# Is it legal to turn across a double solid yellow line?

Tags: california, driving, oregon

[image: turn I am asking about]

Is this a legal turn in Oregon? The single lane road is a private driveway and the two lane road is Highway 101.

What about California?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

[Oregon](https://www.oregon.gov/odot/forms/dmv/37.pdf)

> Double solid yellow line – Indicates passing is not allowed for both directions of traffic. You may turn left, to enter or exit a roadway, across double solid yellow lines after waiting for oncoming traffic to clear.

[California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/handbook/california-driver-handbook/lane-control/)

> Two solid yellow lines indicate no passing. Never drive to the left of these lines unless you are:
>
> - Turning left across a single set of double yellow lines to enter or exit a driveway or private road, or make a U-turn.

More broadly, this is the rule in every jurisdiction I’ve ever driven in. Multiple countries in four continents.

Comment: Thank you! Google Maps puts me on a somewhat convoluted route to avoid a turn like this. I guess that's a bug in Google Maps?

Comment: @Someone  Do you mind telling us what intersection it is? There may be another reason like there's a no-left-turn sign although it might only be that the road is very busy and it's difficult to make a left turn there.

Comment: It's right by my house, so I would rather not. There is no no-left-turn sign. It is a busy road and you do sometimes have to wait for a while, so that's probably why.

Comment: @Someone Yes. The US National Park service have a name for that “death by Google” due to it telling people to go down closed or non-trafficable roads. Google maps always wants me to 7-turn at traffic lights despite that being illegal in my jurisdiction and it will often tell you to go the wrong way down one-way roads.

Comment: Note that in California it _is_ illegal to turn left across a double-double yellow line.